# $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm confused. I've read that for $1\leq p<q<\infty$ following inclusions are true:

$$\mbox{1)}\qquad \ell^p\subset\ell^q$$

$$\mbox{2)}\qquad L^q\subset L^p$$

My question is - why inclusions are opposite? Isn't $\ell^p$ a special case of $L^p$? (with counting measure)

It would be nice if somebody clarified it to me...

Comment: Perhaps in this context, $L^p$ refers explicitly to $L^p[0,1]$ under the usual measure

Comment: So in general, if it refers to all functions integrable with p-th power in some emasure space, then its not true?

Comment: It would seem that the $\ell^p$ spaces are a counterexample by your reasoning.

Comment: Moreover, in $L^p(\Bbb R)$, neither inclusion holds.

Comment: so it holds only for compact subsets of real line?

Comment: 2) holds for finite measure spaces. $\ell_p$ is an $L_p$ space, but the underlying measure space (counting measure on $\Bbb N$) isn't a finite measure.

Comment: I didn't know that, it makes sense now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

2) Is true if the base set has finite measure and 1) is true if every element is an atom.